# Angularfire user registration, login, logout and REST api

Tags: rest, angularfire

It is possible to use angularfire user's registration / login, and after it use a normal REST api to communicate with data on firebase? Angularfire return a uid after user registration. How can I authenticate every REST request with this uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the AngularFire authentication completes, you get an `authData` object from Firebase. A [code snippet from the AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html):

```
  auth.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
    $scope.authData = authData;
  }).catch(function(error) {
```

In `authData.token` you will find a JSON Web Token that can be used with the REST API.